# iPhone Mic Level : Code works in one project, not in another

Tags: iphone, microphone, avaudiorecorder

This [tutorial](http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/) code works fine for me. I set it up to spit out the value of lowPAssResult. Run it on the phone, sure enough, as expected...

2011-07-04 14:28:08.672 MicBlow[280:707] Mic blow detected : 0.036449
...etc, The value goes up if I blow into it. All good.

But when I take it and put it in my own project framework, it doesn't work. I put this code in my init function...

```
//Set up the mic stuff
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];

NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                          nil];

NSError *error;

recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];

if (recorder) 
{
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    [recorder record];
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;        
    levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.03 target: self selector: @selector(levelTimerCallback:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
}
```

And added this callback

```
- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer {
[recorder updateMeters];

const double ALPHA = 0.05;
double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;  

    NSLog(@"Mic blow detected -  peakPowerForChannel : %f, lowPassResults: %f",peakPowerForChannel,lowPassResults);
}
```

And the output looks like this;

2011-07-04 14:30:32.974 MinuteGames[290:707] Mic blow detected : 0.000001
repeatedly. Every frame

No matter how much blowing I do. Please help, I'm sure this must be somethgn simple!